# React Native bottom tab navigator element is not assignable

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am new to React and TypeScript and I created an app with Expo Go that contains the React Bottom Tab Navigator (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/). My problem is that the example does not define the types for the `{navigation}` parameter and I would like to solve this.

Note: it works without defining the type, but I would like to learn and understand how to fix it...

I have a `Navigation.tsx` containing my root stack and the tabs (I hope I limited it to the relevant parts)

```js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
   
declare global {
    namespace ReactNavigation {
        interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList { }
    }
}
    
type RootStackParamList = {
    Tabs: NavigatorScreenParams<RootTabParamList> | undefined;
    Modal: undefined;
    NotFound: undefined;
};

export type RootStackScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootStackParamList> = NativeStackScreenProps<
    RootStackParamList,
    Screen
>;
    
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();
    
type RootTabParamList = {
    About: undefined;
    Test: undefined;
};
    
export type RootTabScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootTabParamList> = CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<RootTabParamList, Screen>,
    NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
>;
   
export default function Navigation({ colorScheme }: { colorScheme: ColorSchemeName }) {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer
            linking={LinkingConfiguration}
            theme={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
        >
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
                // (!) Problem line
                <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }}/>
                <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
                </Stack.Group>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

I found out which is the right type for the `{navigation}` in one of the tabs, e.g. `About.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { Text, View } from '../ui/Components';
import { RootTabScreenProps } from '../ui/Navigation';

export default function About({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<'About'>) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>About</Text>
      <View style={styles.separator} lightColor="#eee" darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" />
      <Text>/screens/About.tsx</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.replace('Tabs')}>
        <Text>Go to home screen!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But I can't find the right type for the `{navigation}` in the root components (no tabs), like `NotFound.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { Text, View } from '../ui/Components';

// (!) Problem line
export default function NotFoundScreen({ navigation }: ?????) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>This screen doesn't exist.</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.replace('Tabs')} style={styles.link}>
        <Text style={styles.linkText}>Go to home screen!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Without the type, I (of course) get an error in `NotFound.tsx`, that

> Binding element 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I tried `RootStackScreenProps<'NotFound'>`, which will let the error above disappear, but instead I get an error in `Navigation.tsx` on line `<Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }}/>`:

> Type '({ navigation }: RootStackScreenProps<"NotFound">) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "NotFound"> | undefined'.
> Type '({ navigation }: RootStackScreenProps<"NotFound">) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
> Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RootStackScreenProps<"NotFound">': navigation, route

So... **What is the right type to use here?**

Comment: I thought @react-navigation was written in typescript. I think you just need to find the type to import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react navigation was written in typescript, so any type you would need relating to it probably exists. [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens) they cover typing a Stack Navigator, and its same premises for a bottom tab navigator. You just need to export `RootStackParamList` and import `NativeStackScreenProps` in your `NotFound.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../ui/Navigation';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Text, View } from '../ui/Components';

type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>; // don't use <Screen> here

export default function NotFoundScreen({ navigation }: Props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>This screen doesn't exist.</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.replace('Tabs')} style={styles.link}>
        <Text style={styles.linkText}>Go to home screen!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, that I can move the type declaration to the individual file. But here it doesn't solve my issue: the types in `About.tsx` are fine, but I cannot acheive the same in `NotFound.tsx`

Comment: Sorry about that I've added `NotFound.tsx`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Just tried it out, but that still didn't resolve the issue. The problem remains + I get an error in `NotFound.tsx` that `Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'BottomTabNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "NotFound", undefined>'.`.

Comment: I think the reason is, that the `navigation` then is missing the `NativeStackScreenProps` type and I was able to resolve this 2nd error by using `type Props = CompositeScreenProps<BottomTabScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'NotFound'>,NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>>;`.

Comment: But then still the error in `Navigation.tsx` as shown in the original question remains. I think the issue is, that `NotFound` is not a Tab but part of the RootStack = a different type then `About`.

Comment: Thanks for year help. I now was able to find a solution :) (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76251878/4090157) and updated your answer accordingly.

Comment: I will accept the answer as soon as my edits have been approved (don't have enough reputation to do so yet).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @phantomspooks and his answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76248413/4090157), I think I now understand the types a bit better.

I was finally able to resolve my problem by making the following changes:

1. Remove `<Screen>` from `export type RootStackScreenProps` in `Navigation.tsx`

```js
export type RootStackScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<
    RootStackParamList
>;
```

2. Use that type in `NotFound.tsx`

```js
export default function NotFoundScreen({ navigation }: RootStackScreenProps) {
    ...
}
```